# Github pages: why my site has different styles after fork?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to get a Jekyll site on GitHub without having to locally install Jekyll, so I just browsed [this list](https://github.com/topics/jekyll-theme) until I found a couple themes I liked and then tried forking them (I intend to edit and customize the files in the browser, without having to clone a local repository). But I keep getting a different version from what I fork.

For instance, I forked https://github.com/codeasashu/hcz-jekyll-blog, and from the live demo I expect it to look like this:
[image]

However, right after forking (no changes made to files yet) I get this:
[image]

The same happened with other themes. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do check if the empty base URL has any link to what you see: [`codeasashu/hcz-jekyll-blog/blob/master/_config.yml`](https://github.com/codeasashu/hcz-jekyll-blog/blob/master/_config.yml#L8-L9).

Note that, according to [issues/15](https://github.com/codeasashu/hcz-jekyll-blog/issues/15#issuecomment-241217167), the `gh_pages` branch of that repo acts as a demo, not the `master` branch. In [`gh_pages` branch, there is a baseurl](https://github.com/codeasashu/hcz-jekyll-blog/blob/gh-pages/_config.yml#L8-L9).